# Can you redirect to another html page then to the section with id?

Tags: html, href

Trying to go from a shopping cart back to a one page html document and to the section of products.When user hits continue browsing.

is there a way to go like: ->  href="index.html #products"

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is. You basically have the right idea down, just put it all together:

```
<a href="somesite.html#products">Link to Products</a>
```

Now you just have to make sure that your Products section has the proper associated ID

```
<div id="products">Products DIV</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Save your poiter in a session or html5 storage when you leave the page, most probably it would be when they click on checkout.
When they click on continue browsing just check if that session or storage variable is there bring them back to where they left. You can even apply filters or do whatever you have stored to retrieve it back and use it.
The part you need is to find out

- How to get location of area they left from
- How to use session or local storage
- How to check if location is stored and
- Redirect to that section either on page or redirect url using id etc

Andwers to all of the above are on Stackoverflow already just matter of search, implement and test.